# Version matching in makefile

Tags: makefile

I am new to make. Suppose I have a makefile which has atarget, the target will kick off different compile command base on the version: From version 1.x.x to version 3.x.x, it will kick off command 1. While version 4.x.x or above, it will kick off command 2.

```
run-%: %.txt
   <if %.txt is in between 1.x.x and 3.x.x, kick off command 1 with %.txt as input>
   <else kick off command 2 with %x.txt as input>
```

User will run it like this:

```
make run-2.2.0
```

Does make provide some sort of pattern matching?

Comment: Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728372/version-number-comparison-inside-makefile/60206580#60206580)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like glob's `[1-3]` if that's what you mean by "pattern matching".  All you can do is write multiple rules unfortunately:

```
run-1.%: 1.%.txt
    <command1>
run-2.%: 2.%.txt
    <command1>
run-3.%: 3.%.txt
    <command1>

run-%: %.txt
    <command2>
```

Comment: You can potentially simplify this various ways: assign `COMMAND1 = <command1>` then use `$(COMMAND1)` in the three recipes to reduce duplication.  If you wanted to get very fancy you could use `eval` to avoid writing the rule multiple times but if there are really only three "old versions" it's probably simpler to read and understand to just write it out three times.