# Makefile - Assigning Variable according to a Conditional

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to adapt the Example from the Official Documentation of *GNU make* to my Use Case:
[GNU make - Example of a Conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example)

```
libs_for_gcc = -lgnu
normal_libs =

ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
  libs=$(libs_for_gcc)
else
  libs=$(normal_libs)
endif

foo: $(objects)
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(libs)
```

So, I created this Prototype:

```
libs_for_gcc="gcc libs"
normal_libs="normal libs"
libs=


all: do_nothing
    @echo "all: done."


do_nothing:
    @echo "do_nothing: done."


example:
    @echo "example: go ..."
    @echo "example - cc: '$(CC)'"
    @echo "libs_for_gcc: $(libs_for_gcc)"
    @echo "normal_libs: $(normal_libs)"
    @echo "libs: $(libs)"
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
    libs=$(libs_for_gcc) && echo "libs: '$$libs'"
    @echo "example - libs: '$(libs)'"
else
    libs=$(normal_libs) && echo "libs: '$$libs'"
    @echo example - libs: $(libs)
endif
    @echo "example - libs: '$(libs)'"
    @echo "example: done."


test: libs += " -Ddebug"
test: example foo


bar:
    @echo "bar: go ..."
ifeq (${libs}, "")
    @echo "bar - libs: empty"
    @echo "assigning libs"
    libs=$(libs_for_gcc)
else
    @echo "bar - libs: not empty"
    @echo "bar - libs: '${libs}'"
endif
    @echo "bar - libs: '${libs}'"
    @echo "bar: done."



foo: 
    @echo "foo: go ..."
ifneq ("$(libs)", "")
    @echo "foo - libs: not empty"
    @echo "foo - libs: '$(libs)'"
else
    @echo "foo - libs: empty"
endif
    @echo "foo: done."
```

Now when I run the Default Target with `$ make`
it just produces:

```
$ make
example: go ...
example - cc: 'cc'
libs_for_gcc: gcc libs
normal_libs: normal libs
libs: 
libs="normal libs"
example - libs:
example - libs: ''
example: done.
```

I see that the value of `libs` **was not changed** as intended.

When I run the `make bar` Target it produces:

```
$ make bar
bar: go ...
bar - libs: not empty
bar - libs: ''
bar - libs: ''
bar: done.
```

Here `libs` is **not empty** but it has **nothing** inside.

And when I run the `make foo` target it produces:

```
$ make foo
foo: go ...
foo - libs: empty
foo: done.
```

Here `libs` is understood as **empty**

As I see that `libs` is not changed correctly I tried to change the syntax to:

```
example:
    # [...]
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
    libs := $(libs_for_gcc)
    @echo "example - libs: '$(libs)'"
else
    libs := $(normal_libs)
    @echo example - libs: $(libs)
endif
```

But then I get the *GNU make* Error:

```
$ make
example: go ...
example - cc: 'cc'
libs_for_gcc: gcc libs
normal_libs: normal libs
libs: 
libs := "normal libs"
/bin/sh: 1: libs: not found
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'example' failed
make: *** [example] Error 127
```

I couldn't find any documentation about this behaviour so I appreciate any advise.

---

**Edit:**

- Added `all` and `test` Targets.

---

**Background:**

The *GNU make* Command is an important part of the toolchain for packaging and deploying software and thus important in the daily work of System Administrators and DevOps Engineers.

- The *Debian* and *RPM* Packaging uses *GNU make* to package software.
  [Makefile Driven Packaging](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch08.en.html#makefile-sh)
  It runs the `./configure && make && make install` command sequence.
- The *Travis CI* Workflow uses *GNU make* for running testsuites.
  [C Language Automated Testing](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/c/#what-this-guide-covers)
  It runs the `./configure && make && make test` sequence.

All the completely different Use Case are managed by the **same Makefile**.
Now for my concrete Use Case I'm working on setting up the *Travis CI* Workflow Sequence to enable **Automated Testing** for my static linked Source Code Library.
So, contrary to the Packaging Sequence the Automated Testing Sequence requires Debug Features and advanced Output Evaluation to produce a meaningful Test.
I want the Test to check the **Error Report** and also the **Memory Usage Report** to alert me of any hidden errors.

Using the Advice about setting the Variable at the Target Declaration Line I was able to change `libs` for `test`, `example` and `foo` targets.
I also saw the important hint about the *Bash* Variable `libs` which is only valid on the same line:

```
$ make
do_nothing: done.
all: done.

$ make test
example: go ...
example - cc: 'cc'
libs_for_gcc: gcc libs
normal_libs: normal libs
libs:  -Ddebug
libs="normal libs" && echo "libs: '$libs'" ;
libs: 'normal libs'
example - libs:  -Ddebug
example - libs: ' -Ddebug'
example: done.
foo: go ...
foo - libs: empty
foo - libs: ' -Ddebug'
foo: done.
```

The Recipe `libs=$(libs_for_gcc) && echo "libs: '$$libs'"` shows that a new *Bash* Variable `libs` was created and it did not affect the *GNU make* Variable.

Still the Conditional `ifneq ($(libs),)` cannot detect that `libs` was already set for the `test` target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved to get my Makefile `make test` Target working.
[`make test` Test Suite with *GNU make*](https://travis-ci.com/github/bodo-hugo-barwich/hash-lists/builds/207246542)

The key was to understand that there are 3 different contexts where a *GNU make* Variable can be assigned.
And that *GNU make* often needs helper functions because of some strange issues with **Conditionals**
These issues are mostly undocumented and only can be solved by **Try and Error** and searching on *StackOverflow.com*

**1.** The first, easiest and best documented context to assign a Variable is in **Global Context** as seen in the official documentation and the first answer.
[*GNU make* - Example of a Conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example)

```
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
  libs=$(libs_for_gcc)
else
  libs=$(normal_libs)
endif
```

The Global Variable `${libs}` has global visibility.

**2.** The next context which is not that obvious but still documented in the Official Documentation is in the **Target Definition Line**
[*GNU make* - Target-specific Variable Values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html)

```
test: libs += " -Ddebug"
test: example foo
```

Here `${libs}` is valid for the `test` Target and all dependent Targets that it calls.
But the only Condition is the Target itself.

**3.** To assign dynamically a Variable in the context of a Target is to use the `$(eval )` Function in combination with the `$(shell )` Function as seen in this *StackOverflow.com* Post:
[Assign a Variable as Result of a Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157083/makefile-how-to-assign-a-commands-output-and-exit-code-to-a-variable)

```
test: examples_debug
        # [...]
        $(eval error := $(shell cat ./demo_error.log))
ifeq ($(strip $(error)),)
        @$(ECHO) "NO Error: '${error}'"
else
        @$(ECHO) "Error detected: '${error}'"
        $(error "Demo failed with Error [Code: '${error_code}']")
        @exit 1
endif
```

Here `${error}` is read from a File. Additionally the `$(strip )` Function is required to be able to check if it is **empty**, which is some of the undocumented issues that *GNU make* has and are wierd to *Bash* Developers.

**4.** Another method that works but does not use a *Makefile* Variable and is somewhat bulky is evaluating the Variable entirely in *Bash* in **1 single Line** which can be found at: [Check Variable with *Bash* Command Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16722803/7774231) and was also hinted by the previous Answer.
Which would look like:

```
test: test_debug
        # [...]
        leak=`cat ./test_heap.log | grep -i "unfreed memory blocks" | awk '{print $$1}'` ; if [ $$leak -gt 1 ]; then echo "Memory Leaks: $$leak" && exit 1; else echo "Memory Leaks: NONE"; fi ;
```

Here `$$leak` is a *Bash* Variable and **only valid within the same Line**.
An approach that is somewhat similar to the *GitHub Workflow* Command Logic. (Actually is was directly ported from the *GitHub Workflow* for the same Project)

As about **Evaluation of Conditionals** there are many undocumented issues in *GNU make* that require *Bash* Workarounds to achieve the goal.
As documented at:
[Preprocessing Numerical Values for the Makefile Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732456/7774231)
There are issues with comparing Numbers and it is impossible to compare against `0` which is extremely important **Exit Code** for Command Line Applications.
So the Workaround looked somewhat like:

```
test: test_debug
        # Run the Testsuite Application
        # [...]
        $(eval error_code := $(shell export HEAPTRC="log=test_heap.log" ; echo -n "" >./test_heap.log ; ${wrkdir}/tests_hash-lists.dbg.run 2>./tests_error.log 1>./tests_exec.log ; echo "$$?"))
        @$(ECHO) Application Tests: Execution finished with [${error_code}]
        #Application Tests Execution Report
        # [...]
        $(eval is_error := $(shell if [ "${error_code}" = "0" ]; then echo false ; else echo true ; fi ;))
ifeq (${is_error}, true)
        @$(ECHO) Exit Code non cero: '${error_code}'
        @$(ECHO) "Tests failed with Error [Code: '${error_code}']"
        @exit ${error_code}
endif
```

In this use case `${error_code}` is tested with a *Bash* Conditional to populate the Helper Variable `${is_error}` with `true` or `false` which then can be checked in *GNU make*.

---

**Discussion:**

The `test` Target cannot just exit on error.
For troubleshooting a failed **Automated Test** it is crucial to see the **Exit Code**, the **Error Message** and the **Heap Report**.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between your example and the one in the GNU make manual is that in the GNU make manual they are setting a *make* variable named `libs` (they are assigning the variable outside of any recipe).

In your usage you are assigning a *shell* variable named `libs` (you are assigning it inside the recipe, indented with a TAB).

That's why you get an error when you try to use `:=`, because that's a *make* assignment and is not a valid *shell* assignment.

Then in your `echo` you print the *make* variable `$(libs)` which has not been set at all.  Further, every logical line of the recipe is run in inside it's own shell.  So you are running the equivalent of:

```
/bin/sh -c 'libs="gcc libs"'
/bin/sh -c 'echo '
```

so even if you DID change your echo command to print the shell variable (via `$$libs`) it would be empty because the previous shell, where it was set, has exited.

You want to use the same syntax as in the example: take the assignment of the variable OUT of the recipe and set the make variable instead:

```
libs_for_gcc = gcc libs
normal_libs = normal libs

ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
  libs = $(libs_for_gcc)
else
  libs = $(normal_libs)
endif

example:
        @echo "example: go ..."
        @echo "example - cc: '$(CC)'"
        @echo "libs_for_gcc: $(libs_for_gcc)"
        @echo "normal_libs: $(normal_libs)"
        @echo "libs: $(libs)"
        @echo "example - libs: '$(libs)'"
        @echo "example: done."
```

Comment: I always recommend that _ALL_ make variable assignments use whitespace around the assignment operator: this helps remind yourself of the difference since shell variables cannot have spaces around the `=`.  And, you should not add quotes around entire values in make variables like you do in shell variables: make variables do not need quoting.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explication. I also noticed this big difference between the documentation example and my use case. But now in my use case I need `libs` to have a different value according to each **Target**. Let's say `debug`, `release` and `test` targets. How can I change the value of `libs` for each **Target**?

Comment: Well, you'll have to describe how you want to do it: you don't show in your example any examples of how you might specify which different values you want.  One common way things like this are handled is through constructed macro names; see this blog post for an example: http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/  Another option is with target-specific variables: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Comment: thank you, your explication about the _Bash_ Variable `$$libs` and the limited Validity Range was very helpful.

Comment: @MadScientist - is the five-liner syntax (`ifeq`/`else`/`endif`) the only way to conditionally set a variable in a Makefile? I'm trying to learn whether there's a way to do it as a one-liner, by some manner of "embedding" the `ifeq` in the assignment? I.e. similar to the C one-liner conditional assignment, e.g. `int i = (x == 5 ? 42 : 43);`

Comment: There is an `$(if ...)` function.  See the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html  The tricky think in makefile syntax is writing the condition, so how you do it depends almost exclusively on the kind of condition you're trying to write.